# access crash when changing form filter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

here's my form.

[image]

Access always crash if I do these steps:

1. Do a search for the year 2012
2. Then do a search for the proposal number 12-100 (which exists)

No matter what, if I do the year search then the search for the proposal number or vice versa. it will crash. By crash,I mean access stop working and has to restart.

They both work if I close the form before to do the second one.

Here's the code for my find and clear button (That's almost all the code of my form).

```
 Private Sub btnFind_Click()
    If (Not IsNull(txtResearch) And txtResearch <> "") Then
        Me.Filter = "ProposalNo = '" & txtResearch & "'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    ElseIf (Not IsNull(txtYear) And txtYear <> "") Then
        Me.Filter = "pyear = " & txtYear
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If

End Sub



Private Sub btnClear_Click()
    txtResearch = ""
    txtYear = ""
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```

The problem is it the way I set the filter? I wasn't sure about `Me.FilterOn`

Also, I did try to compact and repair but no luck

Thank you

Comment: This is with an SQL Server back-end yesno? have you tried just setting the recordsource using a where statement?

Comment: Yes it's an SQL Server Back-End. I will try right now with the record source.

Comment: Wow, no crash... When should I use filter then?

Comment: Apparently there may be a bit of a problem with filters and SQL Server, but I am not well enough up on the subject. You might also like to look at Allen Browne's notes here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/access-crashes-remove-filter-sub-form-t2772609.html

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you. Can you write your comments as an answer plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there may be a bit of a problem with filters and SQL Server, but I am not well enough up on the subject. You might also like to look at Allen Browne's notes here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/access-crashes-remove-filter-sub-form-t2772609.html

You may wish to consider setting the recordsource with a where statement rather than using filters.