# Filter Property on Access form not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, filter

For the past couple days I have been trying to apply a filter to an Access-2010 form.  The record source of the form is a table.  The filter is created from a series of buttons on the form.  Here are the buttons that construct the filter

[image]

Event procedure for List button:

```
Private Sub btnListInterfaceLog_Click()
    Dim List As String
    List = StartList()
End Sub
```

StartList() function code

```
Private Function StartList()

   Dim strWhereClause As String
   strWhereClause = MakeWhere()  
   MsgBox strWhereClause

   Me.FilterOn = True
   Me.Filter = strWhereClause
   Me.Requery

End function
```

Code for MakeWhere()

```
Private Function MakeWhere() As String

   Dim whereClause As String
   whereClause = ""

   If Me![cboinstrument].Enabled = True And Me![cboinstrument] <> "" Then
       whereClause = RvAppendCondition(whereClause, "InstrumentName", "String", "=", Me![cboinstrument])
   End If

   If Me![cboFolder].Enabled = True And Me![cboFolder] <> "" Then
    whereClause = RvAppendCondition(whereClause, "folder", "String", "=", Me![cboFolder])
   End If

   If Me![BatchFrom].Enabled = True And Me![BatchFrom] > 0 And Me![BatchTo].Enabled = True And Me![BatchTo] > 0 Then
    whereClause = RvAppendCondition(whereClause, "BatchID", "Number", "=", Me![BatchFrom], Me![BatchTo])
   End If

   If Me![AnalyzedFrom].Enabled = True And Me![AnalyzedFrom] > 0 And Me![AnalyzedTo].Enabled = True And Me![AnalyzedTo] > 0 Then
    whereClause = RvAppendCondition(whereClause, "Dateofbatch", "Date", "=", Me![AnalyzedFrom], Me![AnalyzedTo])
   End If

   MakeWhere = whereClause

 End Function
```

The RvAppendCondition function takes a given string and adds a new parameter to the where statement.  It has been tested numerous times and works so you do not have to focus on it so much.  if asked I can include the code for reference.

For example : If All I do is choose the instrument name (From: combo box) and leave the rest blank then press list, strWhereClause will msgbox " [InstrumentName] = 'ICPMS' " and I get no errors yet when I go to the main form's properties nothing is listed under filter.  How do I make it so a value will appear in the filter property when I press list.  (sidenote: all functions have error statements I took them out to make them shorter)

Comment: Rather than a filter, could you just change the recordset? eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088701/access-crash-when-changing-form-filter/13089178#13089178

Comment: Can the where statement for the recordset be dynamic?

Comment: Sure, just set the recordsource for the form to an sql string. It might be very slow if you don't have good indexes.

Comment: I usually set `FilterOn = true` after setting the `Filter` string. Are you aware you are not returning anything from `StartList`?

Comment: Are you wanting to set the filter on the form with this search or another form? is `Me.Filter = strWhereClause` on `frmInstrumentInterface` or the "parent form"?

Comment: Does the fact that startlist() doesn't return a value effect whether the filter is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your CODE should be.

```
Private Sub btnListInterfaceLog_Click()
   Dim strWhereClause As String
   strWhereClause = MakeWhere()  
   MsgBox strWhereClause

   Me.Filter = strWhereClause
   Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Function MakeWhere() As String

   Dim whereClause As String

   If Me![cboinstrument].Enabled = True And Me![cboinstrument] <> "" Then
        whereClause = whereClause & "(InstrumentName = '" & Me![cboinstrument] & "') AND "
   End If

   If Me![cboFolder].Enabled = True And Me![cboFolder] <> "" Then
        whereClause = whereClause & "(folder = '" & Me![cboFolder] & "') AND "
   End If

   If Me![BatchFrom].Enabled = True And Me![BatchFrom] > 0 And Me![BatchTo].Enabled = True And Me![BatchTo] > 0 Then
        whereClause = whereClause & "(BatchID BETWEEN " & Me![BatchFrom] & " AND " & Me![BatchTo] & ") AND "
   End If

   If Me![AnalyzedFrom].Enabled = True And Me![AnalyzedFrom] > 0 And Me![AnalyzedTo].Enabled = True And Me![AnalyzedTo] > 0 Then
        whereClause = whereClause & "(Dateofbatch BETWEEN " & Format(Me![AnalyzedFrom], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                                    " AND " & Format(Me![AnalyzedTo], "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & ") AND "
   End If

   MakeWhere = Left(whereClause, Len(whereClause) - 5)

 End Function
```

Comment: I implemented this code and there was still no string in the Filter property.  I msgbox the strWhereclause and it was "[InstrumentName] = 'ICPMS' AND [BATCHID] BETWEEN 100 AND 100" the batchid was set from 100 to 100 and the FROM: combo box was ICPMS

Comment: But the toggle Filter button in the home tab is highlighted so maybe there is a filter but for some reason it doesn't seem to be effecting the record source?

Comment: Try the edited code, your RvAppendCondition is not placing the right parentheses. Which is very essential in multiple criteria.

Comment: Okay so now the strwhereclause is "(InstrumentName = 'ICPMS') AND (Batchid BETWEEN 100 AND 100)" , the toggle filter button is on, on the main form the filter property is empty, the records being shown do not match the criteria and the filter on Load property is NO (if that matters?).  It seems I can not get anything to appear in the filter property of the main form.

Comment: Probably because you are reapplying the Query, when you use Me.Requery. Try removing that line of code (as shown in my edit).